# Simple Reduce function not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, reduce

There is a challenge that I need to complete. I need to decipher which floor santa is on based on the map provided.

1. Santa starts at Floor 0.
2. "(" means that Santa goes up one floor.
3. ")" means that Santa goes down one floor.

**FUNCTION:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

function decipherMap() {
   fs.readFile('./map.txt', (err, data) => {
     const directions = data.toString();
     const array = directions.split('');
     const floor = array.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
       if (currentValue === '(') {
        return acc += 1
      } else if (currentValue === ')') {
        return acc -= 1
      }
     }, 0)
     console.log('Floor:', floor);
   })
}

decipherMap();
```

**MAP: map.txt**

```
(((())))()((((((((())()(()))(()((((()(()(((()((()((()(()()()()()))(((()(()((((((((((())(()()((())()(((())))()(()(()((()(()))(()()()()((()((()(((()()(((((((()()())()((((()()(((((()(())()(())((())()()))()(((((((())(()())(()(((())(()))((())))(()((()())))()())((((())))(()(((((()(())(((()()((()((()((((((((((())(()())))))()))())()()((((()()()()()()((((((())())(((()())()((()()(((()()()))(((((()))(((()(()()()(()(()(((())()))(()(((()((())()(()())())))((()()()(()()(((()))(((()((((()(((((()()(()())((()())())(()((((((()(()()))((((()))))())((())()()((()(()))))((((((((()))(()()(((())())(())()((()()()()((()((()((()()(((())))(()((())()((((((((()((()(()()(((())())())))(())())))()((((()))))))())))()()))()())((()())()((()()()))(()()(((()(())((((())())((((((((()()()()())))()()()((((()()))))))()((((()(((()))(()()())))((()()(((()))()()())())(((())((()()(())()()()(((())))))()())((()))()))((())()()())()())()()(()))())))())()))(())((()(())))(()(())(()))))(()(())())(()(())(()(()))))((()())()))()((((()()))))())))()()())((())()((()()()))()(((()(()))))(())()()))(((()())))))))))(((())))()))())()))))()()(((())))))))()(()()(()))((()))))((())))((()((())))())))()()(()))())()(()((()())(()(()()())())(()()))()))))(()())()()))()()()()))(()(()(()))))))()(()))()))()()(()((())(()(())))()(((())(())())))))()(()(()))))()))(()()()(())()(()(())))()))))()()(((((())))))())()())())())()())()))))()))))))))())()()()()()()())))()))((())()))())))()((())()))))()))())))))))())()()()))()()(()((((()(((((((()(())((()())((()()))()))))(())))()()()(())((())()())))(())))(())))(((()()))()(())(((()(()))((())))())()))((((()))())()))))))))()(())())))(()))()(()()))())()()(())())))())()()(()())))()((()())(()(())(())))))))))))))(()))))()))))))()()())(()(((((()(()())))())()))(()))()))(()()))()())(()))())()(())((()()))))))())))())()(((())))(()(()))()()))()(()))))))((()())(()))))))()())))()()))))))))((((((((()()()(()))))))()())))())))()()((())()))((())(())))())())))()()()((()((()(())))())()(())))))))))()())))()()()()()()))()))((())())(()(()))))))(()()))()))(())))()))))))))))))(()))))))))()))))()))()())()))()()))))))()))))((()))))(()))())()(())))(()())((((()())))()))))(()))()(()()(())))))())))))()))))))())))())))))())))())())))())(()))))(())()(())))())()))((()()))))))())))((())))))))())))(())))))()()())))))())))))()))))))()))()()()(()(((()())())())(()))())))))((()(())(()))))))))(())))()()()())())(()))))()()()))()))())())())()(())))()(((()((((())))))))()))))))))))))))))))))((())()())(()))))()()))))))(()()(())())))())))((())))((())))))))))))))()))))()(()))))))())))))()))(()()())(()())))))))))()))))))(())))))()()))()())(((())))()))(()))))))))(())())))())))())())())()()))((())()(())()())()))()())(())(()))))()())))(()(((()))))))()(()())()()()))()))))))))()()()(())()())()(((((()))()())())(()))))()()()(())))())))()((()())))(()))())()(()())())(()))()()))((()()))((()()()()())))(())()))(()(())))((()()))))))))())))))))())()()))))))))))))))))(())()(())(())()())())()))()(()))))())())))))()())()(()))()()(())))(())())))))(()))))))))))))))())())(())(())))(((()))()))))())((())(()))())))))))())))))())))()))()))))))))))))())()))))()))))((()))(())))()(())))(())()))()))())))())))))))()(()())())))()()())))(())))))(()))))))))))))(()))()))()))())))(((()()()(())((()())))()())(((()))(())()))((()()()())))())(())(()))))()(((((())))(()))())())))))))((((()()()))())())()(()(()())))))))))()())())))(())))()())(((()(())())()()))())())))))))((()())((()()(()))(()(())))()))()))(()))(()))()()(()(((())((((()))()(()))((())()(()(()())()(()))()())))))(()))()))())()())))())))(())))((())(()())))))()))(())(()))()())()(()()((()(()))))))()(())(()())(())()))(((())()))(()()(()()()))))(()(())))()))))())))))())(()()()()()()(((())))(()()))()((())(((((()()())))(()))(()))()()))(((())())()(((()()()()))))(()))(())())))()())(()()())())))))))()))))((())))()())(()))(()(()))())))))())(())))))()()())())()))()()(())))(()))(())((((((())(()))(()))())()))(()()(())))()))(()()))()))()(())))(())))((()(()))(())()()())())))(((()()())(())()))))))()(((()(((((()()(((())(())))())()((()))))((()())()(())(((())))(((()((()(()(()))(()()))())(()))(())(())))()))))))((((()))()((((()(()))()))()()))))()(()(()))()(()((()(((()(()()(((()))))()(((()(()(()(((()(()())())()()(()(()())())(()((((())(()))()))(((((()()())(())()((()()())))()()(((()()))()((((((((()(())))())((()))))(())))(()))))((()((((()()(())(((((()))(((((((((((((()())))((((()(((()((())())()))((()))()(()()((()()()()(()()(()(()(((())()(()((((((()((()()((())()((((()((()()(()()())((()()()((()((())()(()(((()((())((((())(()))((()(()))(()())()((((((((()(((((((((((()))(()(((()(()()()((((())((())()())()))(())((())(()))(((()((()(())))(()))))((()()))))((((()(()(()())(()(())((((((((()((((()((()(((((()))())()(()))(()()((()(())(((((()(())()(((((()()))))))()(((())()(()()((((())()((())((()(((())(((()))((()()((((()(())))))((()((((()((()((()(((())((()))(((((((()(((()((((((((())()))((((())(((((()((((((((()(((()((()(((()()(((()((((((()()(()((((((((()()(()(()(())((((()())()))))(((()))((((())((((()())((()(())()((()((((((()((((((()(())))()())(((())())())()(())()(()())((()()((((())((((((())(()(((((()((((())()((((()(()(())(()())(((())()((())((((()))()((((((())(()(((()(((()((((((()(((()))(()()())())((()((()())()((((())(((()(()(((((((((())(())))()((()()()()(())((()))(((((((()(((((((((()(()))))(()((((((((()((((()((()()((((((()()(((((((()(()(())()(())((()()()((()(((((()())()(((((()())()()((()(()())(()()()(((()()(((((()((((((()()((()(()()()((((((((((((()((((((((()()(((()())))()(((()()(())())((((()((((()((((()()()(())(())((()(()(((((((((((((((()(())(())))))()()))((()(((()(())((()(((()(()()((((()()(((()(((()(((((()()((()(()(((()))((((((()((((((((()((()((())(((((()(((())(())())((()()))((((())()()((()(((()(((((()()(((()))(((()(()(((((((((((((()))((((((((()(((()))))())((((((((((((())((())((()())(((())((())(()((((((((((()(((())((()()(()((())(((((((((((()))((((((((((((()(()())((()((()((()(()(((()((((((((()()(()((()(()(((()))((()))(((((((((((((()(())((((((())(((()(())(()(()(()((()()))((((()((((()((((())))())((((()((((()))((((((()((((((()((()(((())))((())(()))(()((()((((()((()(((()()))((((()()()(((((((())(((())(()))())((((()())(((()(((((((((((()(()(()((()(((((((((((((((()()((((()((((((((()(((()()((()((((()))(((()(())((((((()((((())()((((()((()))(())()(()(((()((())())((((((()(()(())())(((())(()(()())(((((()((()((())()())(())))(((()(())))))))(((()(((()))()((()(((()()((()())()()))())))(((()))(()(((()(((((((((()(()(((((()()(((()())()()))))()(((()))(((()(()(()(()(()))()(())()))(()(((())))(()))))))))))(())((()((())((()(())()(())((()()((((()()((()()))((())(((()((()(())(())))()(()(((((()((()))())()(((((()()(((()(()((((((())(()))(())()))((()(()()))(())())()))(((())))(()((()(((())(())())))((()()((((((((((((((()((()(()()(()(((()))())()()((()()()(())(()))(()())(((())((())()(())()()(()()(())))((()(((()))))(((()()(()()))())((()((())()))((((()()()())((())))(((()(())(((((()(((((()((()(()((((()()(((()()()(((()())(((()()((((())(()))(((()))(())())((()))(((()((()))(((()()((())((()(((((()((((()()())((()))()((((()((()(()()()(
```

When I run the script through Node, my response is "Floor: Undefined". It's supposed to be "Floor: 280".

Can anyone help me figure out why its getting undefined?

Comment: i get 232 as result with the data.

Comment: Maybe there are other characters which are causing issue, like line terminators. Try using `.filter` method before using `.reduce` method, like so `array.filter(char => ['(', ')'].includes(char)).reduce(reduceFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

The result will be 232. Your code broke, because at the end of the file, it seems, is not `(` or `)`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function decipherMap() {
    fs.readFile('./map.txt', (err, data) => {
        const directions = data.toString();
        const array = directions.split('');
        const floor = array.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
            if (currentValue === '(') {
                return acc + 1;
            } else if (currentValue === ')') {
                return acc - 1;
            } else {
                return acc;
            }
        }, 0);
        console.log('Floor:', floor);
    })
}

decipherMap();
```

At the end of your file is `\r\n`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed when I logged the value of array, at the end there was /r/n. I used a trim method after the toString to help me get rid of the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Just trim any white space using `trim` like this

```
 const directions = data.toString().trim();
```

Also the answer is **232** :)

complete code

```
const fs = require("fs");

function decipherMap() {
  fs.readFile("./map.txt", (err, data) => {
    const directions = data.toString().trim();
    const array = directions.split("");

    const floor = array.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
      if (currentValue === "(") {
        return (acc += 1);
      } else if (currentValue === ")") {
        return (acc -= 1);
      }
    }, 0);
    console.log("Floor:", floor);
  });
}

decipherMap();
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes, I noticed when I logged the value of array, at the end there was /r/n. The trim help me get rid of the white space, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the `setTimeout`, it's just to make the code legible and allow the data to be defined below the actual code.  You logic is fine and returns 232.  You need to always return something in your accumulator though.  Your if/else statement are the only things returning and if it doesn't take either of those paths, it breaks.

```js
let data = "";

const main = () => {
  const vv = data.split("").reduce((acc, v) => {
    if (v === "(") return acc + 1;
    else if (v === ")") return acc - 1;
    return acc; // VERY IMPORTANT!
  }, 0);
  console.log(vv);
};

setTimeout(main);

/* 
 * If you scroll all the way to the end of this 
 * you will see I added a "\n"
 * character to simulate a new line that is likely 
 * at the end of your file.  If you don't 
 * always return as shown above, your code will break.
 */
data = "(((())))()((((((((())()(()))(()((((()(()(((()((()((()(()()()()()))(((()(()((((((((((())(()()((())()(((())))()(()(()((()(()))(()()()()((()((()(((()()(((((((()()())()((((()()(((((()(())()(())((())()()))()(((((((())(()())(()(((())(()))((())))(()((()())))()())((((())))(()(((((()(())(((()()((()((()((((((((((())(()())))))()))())()()((((()()()()()()((((((())())(((()())()((()()(((()()()))(((((()))(((()(()()()(()(()(((())()))(()(((()((())()(()())())))((()()()(()()(((()))(((()((((()(((((()()(()())((()())())(()((((((()(()()))((((()))))())((())()()((()(()))))((((((((()))(()()(((())())(())()((()()()()((()((()((()()(((())))(()((())()((((((((()((()(()()(((())())())))(())())))()((((()))))))())))()()))()())((()())()((()()()))(()()(((()(())((((())())((((((((()()()()())))()()()((((()()))))))()((((()(((()))(()()())))((()()(((()))()()())())(((())((()()(())()()()(((())))))()())((()))()))((())()()())()())()()(()))())))())()))(())((()(())))(()(())(()))))(()(())())(()(())(()(()))))((()())()))()((((()()))))())))()()())((())()((()()()))()(((()(()))))(())()()))(((()())))))))))(((())))()))())()))))()()(((())))))))()(()()(()))((()))))((())))((()((())))())))()()(()))())()(()((()())(()(()()())())(()()))()))))(()())()()))()()()()))(()(()(()))))))()(()))()))()()(()((())(()(())))()(((())(())())))))()(()(()))))()))(()()()(())()(()(())))()))))()()(((((())))))())()())())())()())()))))()))))))))())()()()()()()())))()))((())()))())))()((())()))))()))())))))))())()()()))()()(()((((()(((((((()(())((()())((()()))()))))(())))()()()(())((())()())))(())))(())))(((()()))()(())(((()(()))((())))())()))((((()))())()))))))))()(())())))(()))()(()()))())()()(())())))())()()(()())))()((()())(()(())(())))))))))))))(()))))()))))))()()())(()(((((()(()())))())()))(()))()))(()()))()())(()))())()(())((()()))))))())))())()(((())))(()(()))()()))()(()))))))((()())(()))))))()())))()()))))))))((((((((()()()(()))))))()())))())))()()((())()))((())(())))())())))()()()((()((()(())))())()(())))))))))()())))()()()()()()))()))((())())(()(()))))))(()()))()))(())))()))))))))))))(()))))))))()))))()))()())()))()()))))))()))))((()))))(()))())()(())))(()())((((()())))()))))(()))()(()()(())))))())))))()))))))())))())))))())))())())))())(()))))(())()(())))())()))((()()))))))())))((())))))))())))(())))))()()())))))())))))()))))))()))()()()(()(((()())())())(()))())))))((()(())(()))))))))(())))()()()())())(()))))()()()))()))())())())()(())))()(((()((((())))))))()))))))))))))))))))))((())()())(()))))()()))))))(()()(())())))())))((())))((())))))))))))))()))))()(()))))))())))))()))(()()())(()())))))))))()))))))(())))))()()))()())(((())))()))(()))))))))(())())))())))())())())()()))((())()(())()())()))()())(())(()))))()())))(()(((()))))))()(()())()()()))()))))))))()()()(())()())()(((((()))()())())(()))))()()()(())))())))()((()())))(()))())()(()())())(()))()()))((()()))((()()()()())))(())()))(()(())))((()()))))))))())))))))())()()))))))))))))))))(())()(())(())()())())()))()(()))))())())))))()())()(()))()()(())))(())())))))(()))))))))))))))())())(())(())))(((()))()))))())((())(()))())))))))())))))())))()))()))))))))))))())()))))()))))((()))(())))()(())))(())()))()))())))())))))))()(()())())))()()())))(())))))(()))))))))))))(()))()))()))())))(((()()()(())((()())))()())(((()))(())()))((()()()())))())(())(()))))()(((((())))(()))())())))))))((((()()()))())())()(()(()())))))))))()())())))(())))()())(((()(())())()()))())())))))))((()())((()()(()))(()(())))()))()))(()))(()))()()(()(((())((((()))()(()))((())()(()(()())()(()))()())))))(()))()))())()())))())))(())))((())(()())))))()))(())(()))()())()(()()((()(()))))))()(())(()())(())()))(((())()))(()()(()()()))))(()(())))()))))())))))())(()()()()()()(((())))(()()))()((())(((((()()())))(()))(()))()()))(((())())()(((()()()()))))(()))(())())))()())(()()())())))))))()))))((())))()())(()))(()(()))())))))())(())))))()()())())()))()()(())))(()))(())((((((())(()))(()))())()))(()()(())))()))(()()))()))()(())))(())))((()(()))(())()()())())))(((()()())(())()))))))()(((()(((((()()(((())(())))())()((()))))((()())()(())(((())))(((()((()(()(()))(()()))())(()))(())(())))()))))))((((()))()((((()(()))()))()()))))()(()(()))()(()((()(((()(()()(((()))))()(((()(()(()(((()(()())())()()(()(()())())(()((((())(()))()))(((((()()())(())()((()()())))()()(((()()))()((((((((()(())))())((()))))(())))(()))))((()((((()()(())(((((()))(((((((((((((()())))((((()(((()((())())()))((()))()(()()((()()()()(()()(()(()(((())()(()((((((()((()()((())()((((()((()()(()()())((()()()((()((())()(()(((()((())((((())(()))((()(()))(()())()((((((((()(((((((((((()))(()(((()(()()()((((())((())()())()))(())((())(()))(((()((()(())))(()))))((()()))))((((()(()(()())(()(())((((((((()((((()((()(((((()))())()(()))(()()((()(())(((((()(())()(((((()()))))))()(((())()(()()((((())()((())((()(((())(((()))((()()((((()(())))))((()((((()((()((()(((())((()))(((((((()(((()((((((((())()))((((())(((((()((((((((()(((()((()(((()()(((()((((((()()(()((((((((()()(()(()(())((((()())()))))(((()))((((())((((()())((()(())()((()((((((()((((((()(())))()())(((())())())()(())()(()())((()()((((())((((((())(()(((((()((((())()((((()(()(())(()())(((())()((())((((()))()((((((())(()(((()(((()((((((()(((()))(()()())())((()((()())()((((())(((()(()(((((((((())(())))()((()()()()(())((()))(((((((()(((((((((()(()))))(()((((((((()((((()((()()((((((()()(((((((()(()(())()(())((()()()((()(((((()())()(((((()())()()((()(()())(()()()(((()()(((((()((((((()()((()(()()()((((((((((((()((((((((()()(((()())))()(((()()(())())((((()((((()((((()()()(())(())((()(()(((((((((((((((()(())(())))))()()))((()(((()(())((()(((()(()()((((()()(((()(((()(((((()()((()(()(((()))((((((()((((((((()((()((())(((((()(((())(())())((()()))((((())()()((()(((()(((((()()(((()))(((()(()(((((((((((((()))((((((((()(((()))))())((((((((((((())((())((()())(((())((())(()((((((((((()(((())((()()(()((())(((((((((((()))((((((((((((()(()())((()((()((()(()(((()((((((((()()(()((()(()(((()))((()))(((((((((((((()(())((((((())(((()(())(()(()(()((()()))((((()((((()((((())))())((((()((((()))((((((()((((((()((()(((())))((())(()))(()((()((((()((()(((()()))((((()()()(((((((())(((())(()))())((((()())(((()(((((((((((()(()(()((()(((((((((((((((()()((((()((((((((()(((()()((()((((()))(((()(())((((((()((((())()((((()((()))(())()(()(((()((())())((((((()(()(())())(((())(()(()())(((((()((()((())()())(())))(((()(())))))))(((()(((()))()((()(((()()((()())()()))())))(((()))(()(((()(((((((((()(()(((((()()(((()())()()))))()(((()))(((()(()(()(()(()))()(())()))(()(((())))(()))))))))))(())((()((())((()(())()(())((()()((((()()((()()))((())(((()((()(())(())))()(()(((((()((()))())()(((((()()(((()(()((((((())(()))(())()))((()(()()))(())())()))(((())))(()((()(((())(())())))((()()((((((((((((((()((()(()()(()(((()))())()()((()()()(())(()))(()())(((())((())()(())()()(()()(())))((()(((()))))(((()()(()()))())((()((())()))((((()()()())((())))(((()(())(((((()(((((()((()(()((((()()(((()()()(((()())(((()()((((())(()))(((()))(())())((()))(((()((()))(((()()((())((()(((((()((((()()())((()))()((((()((()(()()()(\n";
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed when I logged the value of array, at the end there was /r/n. I understand your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could take another approach and replace `)(` and get later the final length of the string.

```js
 var directions = '(((())))()((((((((())()(()))(()((((()(()(((()((()((()(()()()()()))(((()(()((((((((((())(()()((())()(((())))()(()(()((()(()))(()()()()((()((()(((()()(((((((()()())()((((()()(((((()(())()(())((())()()))()(((((((())(()())(()(((())(()))((())))(()((()())))()())((((())))(()(((((()(())(((()()((()((()((((((((((())(()())))))()))())()()((((()()()()()()((((((())())(((()())()((()()(((()()()))(((((()))(((()(()()()(()(()(((())()))(()(((()((())()(()())())))((()()()(()()(((()))(((()((((()(((((()()(()())((()())())(()((((((()(()()))((((()))))())((())()()((()(()))))((((((((()))(()()(((())())(())()((()()()()((()((()((()()(((())))(()((())()((((((((()((()(()()(((())())())))(())())))()((((()))))))())))()()))()())((()())()((()()()))(()()(((()(())((((())())((((((((()()()()())))()()()((((()()))))))()((((()(((()))(()()())))((()()(((()))()()())())(((())((()()(())()()()(((())))))()())((()))()))((())()()())()())()()(()))())))())()))(())((()(())))(()(())(()))))(()(())())(()(())(()(()))))((()())()))()((((()()))))())))()()())((())()((()()()))()(((()(()))))(())()()))(((()())))))))))(((())))()))())()))))()()(((())))))))()(()()(()))((()))))((())))((()((())))())))()()(()))())()(()((()())(()(()()())())(()()))()))))(()())()()))()()()()))(()(()(()))))))()(()))()))()()(()((())(()(())))()(((())(())())))))()(()(()))))()))(()()()(())()(()(())))()))))()()(((((())))))())()())())())()())()))))()))))))))())()()()()()()())))()))((())()))())))()((())()))))()))())))))))())()()()))()()(()((((()(((((((()(())((()())((()()))()))))(())))()()()(())((())()())))(())))(())))(((()()))()(())(((()(()))((())))())()))((((()))())()))))))))()(())())))(()))()(()()))())()()(())())))())()()(()())))()((()())(()(())(())))))))))))))(()))))()))))))()()())(()(((((()(()())))())()))(()))()))(()()))()())(()))())()(())((()()))))))())))())()(((())))(()(()))()()))()(()))))))((()())(()))))))()())))()()))))))))((((((((()()()(()))))))()())))())))()()((())()))((())(())))())())))()()()((()((()(())))())()(())))))))))()())))()()()()()()))()))((())())(()(()))))))(()()))()))(())))()))))))))))))(()))))))))()))))()))()())()))()()))))))()))))((()))))(()))())()(())))(()())((((()())))()))))(()))()(()()(())))))())))))()))))))())))())))))())))())())))())(()))))(())()(())))())()))((()()))))))())))((())))))))())))(())))))()()())))))())))))()))))))()))()()()(()(((()())())())(()))())))))((()(())(()))))))))(())))()()()())())(()))))()()()))()))())())())()(())))()(((()((((())))))))()))))))))))))))))))))((())()())(()))))()()))))))(()()(())())))())))((())))((())))))))))))))()))))()(()))))))())))))()))(()()())(()())))))))))()))))))(())))))()()))()())(((())))()))(()))))))))(())())))())))())())())()()))((())()(())()())()))()())(())(()))))()())))(()(((()))))))()(()())()()()))()))))))))()()()(())()())()(((((()))()())())(()))))()()()(())))())))()((()())))(()))())()(()())())(()))()()))((()()))((()()()()())))(())()))(()(())))((()()))))))))())))))))())()()))))))))))))))))(())()(())(())()())())()))()(()))))())())))))()())()(()))()()(())))(())())))))(()))))))))))))))())())(())(())))(((()))()))))())((())(()))())))))))())))))())))()))()))))))))))))())()))))()))))((()))(())))()(())))(())()))()))())))())))))))()(()())())))()()())))(())))))(()))))))))))))(()))()))()))())))(((()()()(())((()())))()())(((()))(())()))((()()()())))())(())(()))))()(((((())))(()))())())))))))((((()()()))())())()(()(()())))))))))()())())))(())))()())(((()(())())()()))())())))))))((()())((()()(()))(()(())))()))()))(()))(()))()()(()(((())((((()))()(()))((())()(()(()())()(()))()())))))(()))()))())()())))())))(())))((())(()())))))()))(())(()))()())()(()()((()(()))))))()(())(()())(())()))(((())()))(()()(()()()))))(()(())))()))))())))))())(()()()()()()(((())))(()()))()((())(((((()()())))(()))(()))()()))(((())())()(((()()()()))))(()))(())())))()())(()()())())))))))()))))((())))()())(()))(()(()))())))))())(())))))()()())())()))()()(())))(()))(())((((((())(()))(()))())()))(()()(())))()))(()()))()))()(())))(())))((()(()))(())()()())())))(((()()())(())()))))))()(((()(((((()()(((())(())))())()((()))))((()())()(())(((())))(((()((()(()(()))(()()))())(()))(())(())))()))))))((((()))()((((()(()))()))()()))))()(()(()))()(()((()(((()(()()(((()))))()(((()(()(()(((()(()())())()()(()(()())())(()((((())(()))()))(((((()()())(())()((()()())))()()(((()()))()((((((((()(())))())((()))))(())))(()))))((()((((()()(())(((((()))(((((((((((((()())))((((()(((()((())())()))((()))()(()()((()()()()(()()(()(()(((())()(()((((((()((()()((())()((((()((()()(()()())((()()()((()((())()(()(((()((())((((())(()))((()(()))(()())()((((((((()(((((((((((()))(()(((()(()()()((((())((())()())()))(())((())(()))(((()((()(())))(()))))((()()))))((((()(()(()())(()(())((((((((()((((()((()(((((()))())()(()))(()()((()(())(((((()(())()(((((()()))))))()(((())()(()()((((())()((())((()(((())(((()))((()()((((()(())))))((()((((()((()((()(((())((()))(((((((()(((()((((((((())()))((((())(((((()((((((((()(((()((()(((()()(((()((((((()()(()((((((((()()(()(()(())((((()())()))))(((()))((((())((((()())((()(())()((()((((((()((((((()(())))()())(((())())())()(())()(()())((()()((((())((((((())(()(((((()((((())()((((()(()(())(()())(((())()((())((((()))()((((((())(()(((()(((()((((((()(((()))(()()())())((()((()())()((((())(((()(()(((((((((())(())))()((()()()()(())((()))(((((((()(((((((((()(()))))(()((((((((()((((()((()()((((((()()(((((((()(()(())()(())((()()()((()(((((()())()(((((()())()()((()(()())(()()()(((()()(((((()((((((()()((()(()()()((((((((((((()((((((((()()(((()())))()(((()()(())())((((()((((()((((()()()(())(())((()(()(((((((((((((((()(())(())))))()()))((()(((()(())((()(((()(()()((((()()(((()(((()(((((()()((()(()(((()))((((((()((((((((()((()((())(((((()(((())(())())((()()))((((())()()((()(((()(((((()()(((()))(((()(()(((((((((((((()))((((((((()(((()))))())((((((((((((())((())((()())(((())((())(()((((((((((()(((())((()()(()((())(((((((((((()))((((((((((((()(()())((()((()((()(()(((()((((((((()()(()((()(()(((()))((()))(((((((((((((()(())((((((())(((()(())(()(()(()((()()))((((()((((()((((())))())((((()((((()))((((((()((((((()((()(((())))((())(()))(()((()((((()((()(((()()))((((()()()(((((((())(((())(()))())((((()())(((()(((((((((((()(()(()((()(((((((((((((((()()((((()((((((((()(((()()((()((((()))(((()(())((((((()((((())()((((()((()))(())()(()(((()((())())((((((()(()(())())(((())(()(()())(((((()((()((())()())(())))(((()(())))))))(((()(((()))()((()(((()()((()())()()))())))(((()))(()(((()(((((((((()(()(((((()()(((()())()()))))()(((()))(((()(()(()(()(()))()(())()))(()(((())))(()))))))))))(())((()((())((()(())()(())((()()((((()()((()()))((())(((()((()(())(())))()(()(((((()((()))())()(((((()()(((()(()((((((())(()))(())()))((()(()()))(())())()))(((())))(()((()(((())(())())))((()()((((((((((((((()((()(()()(()(((()))())()()((()()()(())(()))(()())(((())((())()(())()()(()()(())))((()(((()))))(((()()(()()))())((()((())()))((((()()()())((())))(((()(())(((((()(((((()((()(()((((()()(((()()()(((()())(((()()((((())(()))(((()))(())())((()))(((()((()))(((()()((())((()(((((()((((()()())((()))()((((()((()(()()()(',
    length;

do {
    length = directions.length;
    directions = directions.replace(/\)\(/g, '');
} while (directions.length !== length)

console.log('Floor:', directions.length, directions);
```